# Running an immutable setup in production

Tags: deployment

I'm looking into using Docker to streamline my Drupal development workflow. One approach would be to locally create a Docker image for my Drupal installation (not the database, just the Drupal files default found under /var/www/html), and deploy that image to production.

This approach would imply that all changes to the Drupal installation, i.e. all changes to anything under /var/www/html, would be considered immutable or read-only in production. Any changes here would be gone when the next deployment comes along.

I assume the content created by our content creators logged into our production server, is stored in the database, not in the Drupal installation itself.

My question is: Is there any reason why the Docker installation (i.e. files under /var/www/html) would need to be changed when deploying to production, or can these files remain consistent across environments (dev, test, prod)?

Note that I'm quite new to Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

The file containing the credentials for accessing the database, and other site configurations (e.g. the proxy settings, the trusted domains), is inside the server document root (for example, sites/default/settings.php). The answer to *Is there any reason for which the content of the server document root would need to be changed when deploying to production?* is then *yes*.

Add to this the fact that the directory for the public files (e.g. the uploaded images attached to nodes) is by default sites/default/files, you have a reason more to preserve one or more directories under the server document root directory in the production environment.